# Rails4 - how to customize the indexed data while indexing in Elastic Search using SearchKick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

i have recently started using ElasticSearch along with [searchkick gem](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) to index my db data.By default, searchkick gem will index all columns of a model but i want to index only active items(like posts which are published).For example -

```
#####in shop.rb

has_many :dealers
has_one :address
has_one :contact
...blah blah and more has many

###my index data


   def search_data
    { 
      ##XXXXXXXX  why cant i use this XXXXXXXXX
      ###active: true,
      name: name, index: "not_analyzed", 
      capacity: capacity.to_i,
      slug: slug,
      ### i need to add active to so that i can use where(:active => true) in search
      active: active,
      event_type_name: event_types.map(&:name),
      facility_name: facilities.map(&:name),
      ratings: ratings.map(&:stars),
      location: [self.address.latitude, self.address.longitude],
      picture_url: pictures.select{|p| p == pictures.last}.map do |i|{

        original:  i.original_url 

        }
      end
    }
  end
```

**is the above indexing correct?
how can i index only those shops whose attribute value for active is true.?**

Comment: Why it's downvoted ? Doesn't this question make any sense ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

There is a `should_index?` method that looks like exactly what you need:

> By default, all records are indexed. To control which records are
>   indexed, use the should_index? method together with the search_import
>   scope.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  scope :search_import, -> { where(active: true) }

   def should_index?
     active # only index active records
   end
end
```

Comment: So can I say that if I use this along with my search_data block, and then run Reindex..I should be getting only active items ?

Comment: I'm only running off what I just read in the docs, so I can't confirm or deny, unfortunately... sorry :( But it seems like what you need.

Comment: Works like a charm..Thanks